# Why can't you have a non-const char* in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Why does this work:

```
char foo[6] = "shock";`
```

while this does not work:

```
char* bar = "shock"; //error
```

Why does `bar` have to be `const` while `foo` doesn't? Arrays in C decay to pointers, so don't `foo` and `bar` technically have the same types?

Comment: They are not the same type. `foo` is type *array of char* while `bar`is type *pointer to char*.

Comment: @beangod - i compiled c by mistake. my bad,see answer below

Comment: `foo` is a **copy** of the const `"shock"`.  `bar` is a **pointer** to the const `"shock"`.  You can decide whether the copy will be const or not.

Comment: Also, you may _absolutely_ "have a non-const char* in C++".  It simply can't point to something that is const.

Comment: `const char *bar = "shock"; bar[0] = 'c';` -- Try that.

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With this declaration:

```
char foo[6] = "shock";
```

Variable `foo` is type *array of char* and it containes 6 non-const chars. The *string literal* contains const chars which are **copied** into the array on initialization.

While with this declaration:

```
char* bar = "shock"; //error
```

Variable `bar` is type *pointer to char*. You are trying to make it point to the address of `"shock"` which is a string literal containing `const char`.

You can't point a *pointer to non-const char* at a *const char*.

So you must do this:

```
const char* bar = "shock";`
```

Answer (score 7):

Literals are held in reserved areas of memory that are not supposed to be changed by code. Changing the value held at the address storing that literal would mean that every time any other code tried to use that literal, it would find the wrong value in that memory. So it is illegal to modify that memory, and hence illegal to treat it as not constant.

[Source](https://cplusplus.com/forum/general/242111/#msg1075391)

Comment: Very often, it is in read-only blocks of memory so cannot be changed.

Answer (score 3):

because "shock" is a constant, so a pointer to it must be const

for historical reasons C allows this (and causes many errors that lead to SO posts)

Answer (score 1):

```
char* bar = "shock";
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
const char anonymousArray[6] = "shock";
char *bar = anonymousArray;
```

Arrays decays to pointers. That's not the same as actually being pointers.